# How can I load and use a PyTorch (.pth.tar) model

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, pytorch, torch

I am not very familiar with Torch, and I primarily use Tensorflow. I, however, need to use a retrained inception model that was retrained in Torch. Due to the large amount of computing resources required to retrain an inception model for my particular application, I would like to use the model that was already retrained.

This model is saved as a `.pth.tar` file.

I would like to be able to first load this model. So far, I have been able to figure out that I must use the following:

```
model = torch.load('iNat_2018_InceptionV3.pth.tar', map_location='cpu')
```

This seems to work, because `print(model)` prints out a large set of numbers and other values, which I presume are the values for the weights an biases.

After this, I need to be able to classify an image with it. I haven't been able to figure this out. How must I format the image? Should the image be converted into an array? After this, how must I pass the input data to the network?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load and use a pretained PyTorch InceptionV3 model to classify an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844826/how-to-load-and-use-a-pretained-pytorch-inceptionv3-model-to-classify-an-image)

Answer (score 13):

you basically need to do the same as in tensorflow. That is, when you store a network, only the parameters (i.e. the trainable objects in your network) will be stored, but not the "glue", that is all the logic you need to use a trained model.
So if you have a `.pth.tar` file, you can load it, thereby overriding the parameter values of a model already defined.

That means that the general procedure of saving/loading a model is as follows:

- write your network definition (i.e. your `nn.Module` object)
- train or otherwise change the network's parameters in a way you want
- save the parameters using `torch.save`
- when you want to use that network, use the same definition of an `nn.Module` object to first instantiate a pytorch network
- *then* override the values of the network's parameters using `torch.load`

Here's a discussion with some references on how to do this: [pytorch forums](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-save-load-torch-models/718/3)

And here's a super short mwe:

```
# to store
torch.save({
    'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
    'optimizer' : optimizer.state_dict(),
}, 'filename.pth.tar')

# to load
checkpoint = torch.load('filename.pth.tar')
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer'])
```

Comment: @tamtam please do not hijack answers for different questions. The answer above did answer the question asked, as it was on the general flow of loading parameters. I have updated the answer to also give an mwe, however.

Comment: OP never approved your answer and you complied with my question anyways... so it wasn't a hijack. Consider it a request for clarification. Thanks for the mwe, it clarifies things.