# How to load and use a pretained PyTorch InceptionV3 model to classify an image

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I have the same problem as [How can I load and use a PyTorch (.pth.tar) model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857274/how-can-i-load-and-use-a-pytorch-pth-tar-model) which does not have an accepted answer or one I can figure out how to follow the advice given.

I'm new to PyTorch. I am trying to load the pretrained PyTorch model referenced here: https://github.com/macaodha/inat_comp_2018

I'm pretty sure I am missing some glue.

```
# load the model
import torch
model=torch.load("iNat_2018_InceptionV3.pth.tar",map_location='cpu')

# try to get it to classify an image
imsize = 256
loader = transforms.Compose([transforms.Scale(imsize), transforms.ToTensor()])

def image_loader(image_name):
    """load image, returns cuda tensor"""
    image = Image.open(image_name)
    image = loader(image).float()
    image = Variable(image, requires_grad=True)
    image = image.unsqueeze(0)  
    return image.cpu()  #assumes that you're using CPU

image = image_loader("test-image.jpg")
```

Produces the error:

> in ()
>   ----> 1 model.predict(image)
>
> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'predict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problem

Your `model` isn't actually a model. When it is saved, it contains not only the parameters, but also other information about the model as a form somewhat similar to a dict.

Therefore, `torch.load("iNat_2018_InceptionV3.pth.tar")` simply returns `dict`, which of course does not have an attribute called `predict`.

```
model=torch.load("iNat_2018_InceptionV3.pth.tar",map_location='cpu')
type(model)
# dict
```

## Solution

What you need to do first in this case, and in general cases, is to instantiate your desired model class, as per the official guide ["Load models"](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#load).

```
# First try
from torchvision.models import Inception3
v3 = Inception3()
v3.load_state_dict(model['state_dict']) # model that was imported in your code.
```

However, directly inputing the `model['state_dict']` will raise some errors regarding mismatching shapes of `Inception3`'s parameters.

It is important to know what was changed to the `Inception3` after its instantiation. Luckily, you can find that in the original author's `train_inat.py`.

```
# What the author has done
model = inception_v3(pretrained=True)
model.fc = nn.Linear(2048, args.num_classes) #where args.num_classes = 8142
model.aux_logits = False
```

Now that we know what to change, lets make some modification to our *first try*.

```
# Second try
from torchvision.models import Inception3
v3 = Inception3()
v3.fc = nn.Linear(2048, 8142)
v3.aux_logits = False
v3.load_state_dict(model['state_dict']) # model that was imported in your code.
```

And there you go with successfully loaded model!