# Using pre-trained weights in PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, pytorch

I am working on implementing a research paper based on computer vision in PyTorch. I have built the model architecture by referring to the paper. The author has uploaded saved weights on GitHub in ".pth.tar" format. I want to put the same weights in my model so that I can skip training and optimization part and directly get output from the neural net.

The paper is Learning to see in the dark.

Model architecture is as follow:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(32, 12, 1)
        .
        .  
   def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        .
        .    
        return x
net = Net()
```

And it is to be followed by importing trained weight from google drive/cloud storage and defining the function to put the trained weights in the net.

PS: **Model architecture is exactly same for both**

Comment: Do you have a link to the repository for us? It is probably a state_dict which you can load with [load_state_dict](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=load_state_dict#torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict).

Comment: I think it is a load_state_dict, the link to the repository is this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cY3gdAVqkNZo8GnosYGj7ciSkrwasmjP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I load and use a PyTorch (.pth.tar) model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857274/how-can-i-load-and-use-a-pytorch-pth-tar-model)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using google colab

```
#mount drive onto google colab

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Define the path of the weights

```
weights_path="/content/gdrive/My Drive/weights.pth"
```

Extract the tar file

```
!tar -xvf weights.pth.tar
```

Load the weights into the model net

```
net=torch.load(weights_path)
```

Comment: Hi risper `tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors` Received this error while extracting tar file