# how to convert .pth.tar file to a .pt?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, torch

I have a .pth.tar file how can I read in that file and then save it to the same directory in a .pt file?

I am using the modelzoo mlnf file which I cannot find its .pt equivalent.

https://kaiyangzhou.github.io/deep-person-reid/MODEL_ZOO.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you can load your `.pth.tar` file directly with [`torch.load`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.load.html):

```
state_dict = torch.load(model_name)
```

*See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857274/how-can-i-load-and-use-a-pytorch-pth-tar-model) for reference.*

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, it returns

tar xf mlfn.pth.tar && mv mlfn.pth mlfn.pt

tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: How can I save that as a .pt file?

Comment: Well you can save that state dict with [`torch.save`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.save.html): `torch.save(state_dict, new_name)`, where `new_name` has a `pt` file extension...

Comment: That did the trick, thank you.